# ReferenceError: require is not defined when I push on Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, require

I want to push my NodeJS project on heroku but it doesn't work while my project works fine locally.

When I enter "heroku logs --tail" to see errors, I see :

```
2020-08-18T10:39:44.396002+00:00 app[web.1]: const express = require('express')
2020-08-18T10:39:44.396003+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-08-18T10:39:44.396003+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-18T10:39:44.396004+00:00 app[web.1]: ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

This is my "index.js" :

```
const express = require('express')
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev') require('dotenv').config()

const routerIdeas = require('./routes/ideas.js')

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
const app = express()

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
    next()
})

app.use('/api', routerIdeas)

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port : ${PORT}`)
})
```

This is the complete "heroku logs --tail" :

```
 server git:(master) heroku logs --tail        
 ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.7.7 to 7.42.6
2020-08-18T10:17:04.311750+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
2020-08-18T10:17:04.322224+00:00 app[web.1]: file:///app/index.js:1
2020-08-18T10:17:04.322225+00:00 app[web.1]: const express = require('express')
2020-08-18T10:17:04.322226+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-08-18T10:17:04.322226+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-18T10:17:04.322227+00:00 app[web.1]: ReferenceError: require is not defined
2020-08-18T10:17:04.322227+00:00 app[web.1]: at file:///app/index.js:1:17
2020-08-18T10:17:04.322228+00:00 app[web.1]: at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:139:37)
2020-08-18T10:17:04.322228+00:00 app[web.1]: at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:179:24)
2020-08-18T10:17:04.372043+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-08-18T10:17:04.401546+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-08-18T10:39:40.712443+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-08-18T10:39:42.672554+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2020-08-18T10:39:44.381963+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
2020-08-18T10:39:44.396000+00:00 app[web.1]: file:///app/index.js:1
2020-08-18T10:39:44.396002+00:00 app[web.1]: const express = require('express')
2020-08-18T10:39:44.396003+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-08-18T10:39:44.396003+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-18T10:39:44.396004+00:00 app[web.1]: ReferenceError: require is not defined
2020-08-18T10:39:44.396005+00:00 app[web.1]: at file:///app/index.js:1:17
2020-08-18T10:39:44.396005+00:00 app[web.1]: at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:139:37)
2020-08-18T10:39:44.396008+00:00 app[web.1]: at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:179:24)
2020-08-18T10:39:44.439811+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-08-18T10:39:44.472252+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-08-18T10:41:22.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user mika77290@live.fr
2020-08-18T10:41:49.742104+00:00 app[api]: Release v6 created by user mika77290@live.fr
2020-08-18T10:41:49.742104+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 36bf1d35 by user mika77290@live.fr
2020-08-18T10:41:50.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-08-18T10:41:50.965669+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-08-18T10:41:53.104246+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2020-08-18T10:41:54.814879+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
2020-08-18T10:41:54.832290+00:00 app[web.1]: file:///app/index.js:1
2020-08-18T10:41:54.832292+00:00 app[web.1]: const express = require('express')
2020-08-18T10:41:54.832292+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-08-18T10:41:54.832293+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-18T10:41:54.832294+00:00 app[web.1]: ReferenceError: require is not defined
2020-08-18T10:41:54.832294+00:00 app[web.1]: at file:///app/index.js:1:17
2020-08-18T10:41:54.832294+00:00 app[web.1]: at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:139:37)
2020-08-18T10:41:54.832295+00:00 app[web.1]: at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:179:24)
2020-08-18T10:41:54.882959+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-08-18T10:41:54.911539+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-08-18T10:41:57.989717+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=exercice-ideas.herokuapp.com request_id=909d0f01-935e-4d95-bbf0-80e745d61559 fwd="81.249.233.246" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-08-18T10:42:08.284424+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/api/ideas" host=exercice-ideas.herokuapp.com request_id=011b8593-6112-48a0-aa6e-d4c7ab5051b5 fwd="81.249.233.246" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-08-18T10:52:39.587775+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-08-18T10:52:41.637962+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2020-08-18T10:52:43.235694+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
2020-08-18T10:52:43.250839+00:00 app[web.1]: file:///app/index.js:1
2020-08-18T10:52:43.250841+00:00 app[web.1]: const express = require('express')
2020-08-18T10:52:43.250846+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-08-18T10:52:43.250846+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-18T10:52:43.250847+00:00 app[web.1]: ReferenceError: require is not defined
2020-08-18T10:52:43.250847+00:00 app[web.1]: at file:///app/index.js:1:17
2020-08-18T10:52:43.250848+00:00 app[web.1]: at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:139:37)
2020-08-18T10:52:43.250848+00:00 app[web.1]: at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:179:24)
2020-08-18T10:52:43.292178+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-08-18T10:52:43.323908+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-08-18T11:15:25.594409+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-08-18T11:15:28.438563+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2020-08-18T11:15:30.865146+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
2020-08-18T11:15:30.883077+00:00 app[web.1]: file:///app/index.js:1
2020-08-18T11:15:30.883079+00:00 app[web.1]: const express = require('express')
2020-08-18T11:15:30.883080+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-08-18T11:15:30.883081+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-18T11:15:30.883081+00:00 app[web.1]: ReferenceError: require is not defined
2020-08-18T11:15:30.883081+00:00 app[web.1]: at file:///app/index.js:1:17
2020-08-18T11:15:30.883082+00:00 app[web.1]: at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:139:37)
2020-08-18T11:15:30.883083+00:00 app[web.1]: at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:179:24)
2020-08-18T11:15:30.934853+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-08-18T11:15:30.968511+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-08-18T11:33:00.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user mika77290@live.fr
2020-08-18T11:33:34.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-08-18T11:33:34.073417+00:00 app[api]: Release v7 created by user mika77290@live.fr
2020-08-18T11:33:34.073417+00:00 app[api]: Deploy f5b59800 by user mika77290@live.fr
2020-08-18T11:33:35.255435+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-08-18T11:33:37.308185+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2020-08-18T11:33:39.745180+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
2020-08-18T11:33:39.758881+00:00 app[web.1]: file:///app/index.js:21
2020-08-18T11:33:39.758883+00:00 app[web.1]: const express = require('express')
2020-08-18T11:33:39.758884+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-08-18T11:33:39.758884+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-18T11:33:39.758885+00:00 app[web.1]: ReferenceError: require is not defined
2020-08-18T11:33:39.758885+00:00 app[web.1]: at file:///app/index.js:21:17
2020-08-18T11:33:39.758885+00:00 app[web.1]: at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:139:37)
2020-08-18T11:33:39.758886+00:00 app[web.1]: at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:179:24)
2020-08-18T11:33:39.804994+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-08-18T11:33:39.836710+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-08-18T11:33:39.838855+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-08-18T11:33:41.998743+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2020-08-18T11:33:44.652533+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
2020-08-18T11:33:44.674413+00:00 app[web.1]: file:///app/index.js:21
2020-08-18T11:33:44.674415+00:00 app[web.1]: const express = require('express')
2020-08-18T11:33:44.674415+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-08-18T11:33:44.674416+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-18T11:33:44.674416+00:00 app[web.1]: ReferenceError: require is not defined
2020-08-18T11:33:44.674417+00:00 app[web.1]: at file:///app/index.js:21:17
2020-08-18T11:33:44.674417+00:00 app[web.1]: at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:139:37)
2020-08-18T11:33:44.674418+00:00 app[web.1]: at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:179:24)
2020-08-18T11:33:44.736273+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-08-18T11:33:44.780957+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-08-18T11:33:46.586184+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=exercice-ideas.herokuapp.com request_id=af66c9bb-71fb-4575-a9b2-856ef0fd7c92 fwd="81.249.233.246" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I tried pushing the test project provided on the Heroku starter tutorial and there is no problem with "require", so I don't understand.

Thank you in advance to whoever can help me

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem and what I did was in the `package.json` file I removed `type:module` and it worked.

Comment: This worked for me too. If anyone knows why, please advise.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v13.x/api/esm.html#esm_enabling

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted the '.git' and 'Procfile' file.
I also delete the repository on Heroku and create a new one.
I then start the procedure again to link my project to the new repository.
Then I pushed the project and now there are no more errors.

I don't understand why but it works now.